# Look if _id already exists in PouchDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, pouchdb

I need to know if a username is already in use in PouchDB.

My database code so far:

```
const userdb = new PouchDB('users')
userdb.put({
      '_id': data.username,
      'username' : data.username,
      'gender': data.gender,
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

`put` will return a **409 Conflict** when attempting to put a document with an existing `_id`.  There's no need to perform a preflight check.

The snippet below creates a PouchDB using the memory adapter and adds a document with `_id` of 'Jerry Garcia'.  Try to add another user with the same name.

```js
const addUser = async(userName, viewElement) => {
  let response;
  try {
    response = await db.put({
      '_id': userName
    })
  } catch (e) {
    response = e;
  } finally {
    viewElement.innerText = JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 3);
  }
}

// canned test documents
function getDocsToInstall() {
  return [{
    "_id": "Jerry Garcia"
  }]
}

//
//  boilerplate code
//
let db;

// init example db instance
async function initDb() {

  db = new PouchDB('test', {
    adapter: 'memory'
  });

  await db.bulkDocs(getDocsToInstall());
}

initDb();

const getEl = id => document.getElementById(id);
```

```css
.label {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.hints {
  font-size: smaller;
  margin-right: 2em;
}
```

```html
<table id='view'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for='user_name'>User Name:&nbsp;</label>
      <input id='user_name' type='text' placeholder="Jerry Garcia" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button onclick='addUser(getEl("user_name").value,getEl("view_result"))'>Add User</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class='hints'>(enter Jerry Garcia)</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div style='margin-top:2em'></div>
<div>
  <pre id='view_result'></pre>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.1.1/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb.memory.min.js"></script>
```

That being demonstrated, I would hope you are not seriously considering managing user documents  this way - many people share the same name, for one.